PFU/mL count formula in the virus plaque assay
I do virus plaque assay on the cell culture layer. The source of the virus is an animal tissue homogenized in a culture medium (stock). Sometimes I should make series of x10 dilutions, 10ul from stock+90 ul medium and from it again, 10 + 90 medium. So, I have x100 dilution. From that, I plate 0.2 mL. I have got n = 12 plaques, I need find PFU/mL in the stock.
I was told to use formula
PFU/mL = (n * 10e6)/0.2 mL
Could someone explain where 10e6 comes from?
In the case I had m-fold dilution, my formula is next:
PFU/mL = (n * 10e6*10e-m)/0.2 mL
So, my PFU with 1/100 dilution = (12 10e610e-2)/0.2 = 6*10e5 per mL
If I would have 12 plaques at 1/1000 dilutions, that because stock has 10 times more virus, that I am expecting from the formula, but I get:
So, my PFU = (12 10e610e-3)/0.2 = 6*10e4 per mL
What results of my formula is showing to me?
How calculate the initial stock PFU/mL?

Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. You should also note the [homework policy}(https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) and as such - have you looked up the formula and do you know what each component of the formula means? It looks to me like you are just working blindly off someone else's notes... It is always better to go and understand the fundamentals before attempting something.
